# What Structure can I use for Unique keys mapping to unique values?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, collections

Map can solve the O(1) search solution when the key is unique.

But is there a structure in which search by key and search by value both take order O(1)?

Given a structure:

```
Put(key,value)
GetValueOf(Key) in O(1)
GetKeyOf(Value) in O(1)
```

Is there a way such that both searches can be done in order 1 time without using 2 maps ?

I'm particularly interested in java implementations .

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: A structure combining two hash maps would do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In boost there is the [boost::bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html). It is based on two maps that do the two mappings and I believe there is no better solution for the problem you have.

Comment: Cant i do it with out use of 2 maps..??

Comment: You can write a data structure that will hold both hashes of both object types, and two directional pointing. But infact it's the same like holding two maps.

Answer (score 3):

You note that a map can solve the O(1) search solution when the key is unique. You want an O(1) search solution for both keys any values when both are unique. It follows then, that this data-structure would suffice:

```
class YourDoubleHashMap<K,V>() {
  private HashMap<K,V> keyMap;
  private HashMap<V,K> valMap;

  YourDoubleHashMap<K,V>() {
    keyMap = new HashMap<K,V>();
    valMap = new HashMap<V,K>();
  }
  public boolean put(K key,V val) {
    return keyMap.put(key,val) && valMap.put(val,key);
  }
  public V getValueOfKey(K key) {
    return keyMap.get(key);
  }
  public K getKeyOfValue(V val) {
    return valMap.get(val);
  }
}
```

This ***time-memory tradeoff*** approach sacrifices space efficiency in exchange for run-time efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to "Hash" the value properly (in properly i mean that two different values will give you two different hashes with high probability) you can use 2 hash tables, (one from key to value, and the other from value to key)

Comment: Cant i do it with out use of 2 maps..??

Answer (score 1):

The boost bimap is a data structure designed to allow for such requirements. Its quite flexible, and the complexity of lookups depends upon the datastructure you tell it to use to store the underlying values.

[More details here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/the_tutorial/controlling_collection_types.html)

Comment: Is there Any such thing Java ..??

Answer (score 1):

Apache commons collections has a [`BidiMap`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/BidiMap.html) . Or go for Google's [`BiMap`](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html)  .

Comment: You can also use two maps BTW . one mapping value-key and other converse .